# Does hunx have an origin?

Tags: etymology, slang, literature

I was reading Anthony Trollope's The Way We Live Now.  A character calls an old man, "an old hunx" during an argument.  I was wondering if Trollope was writing in an accent or if hunx was an old slang word.  I tried Googling it, but only found websites relating to "Hunx and His Punx." The reference can be viewed [here on Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/5231/5231-h/5231-h.htm#c46).

Comment: *Slang* is not a count noun.  You simply cannot **an old slang*.  It makes no sense. It is not English.

Comment: Fixed to make it "old slang *word*", and added link to the text (which is a 2MB HTML file, btw). It's a legit question, and "hunx" is a rather bizarre word that I'd be curious about origins and meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the entry from [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdict05murrmiss#page/n481/mode/2up):

[image: AN image of a dictionary definition of Hunks (also hunx). Its definition is "A term of obloquy for a surly, crusty, cross-grained old person, a 'bear'; now, usually, a close-fisted, stingy man; a miser. (Generally with close, covertous, niggardly, or other uncomplimentary epithet.)" It is followed by usage citations from 1628 through 1857.]

Ashley Thorndike (*Shakespeare's Theatre*, 1916, 33) states that one of the favorite performers at the Bear Garden in Shakespeare's day was a blind bear named *Old Hunks*; he does not give a source, but the pre-Civil War quotations suggest allusions to the poor beast.

Comment: Aaah, can't beat OED!

Answer (score 4):

There is a reference to the word in [Folk-Etymology: A Dictionary of Verbal Corruptions Or Words Perverted in Form Or Meaning, by False Derivation Or Mistaken Analogy](http://books.google.com/books?id=8AcYAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), an 1882 book by Reverend A. Smythe Palmer.

[image]

And in [Specimens of English Dialect](http://books.google.com/books?id=pyQTAwAAQBAJ&pg=PR3&dq=hunx&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q=hunx&f=false) (Skeat & Elworthy, 1900):
[image]